# json got changed when consuming it via a promise (aws api gatway SDK)

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services

I am using AWS API Gateway generated js SDK for a project in angular 4, I am calling a endpoint using the sdk and getting data successfully. In network tab of the browser the data shown is correct and when I consume that same data using promise

```
.then( response => { console.log(response); }
```

the data printed in console and the data in the network tab is different - before even I use it for my project.

AWS API Gateway js SDK code:

```
getFundAdvisesList(fund: string) {
    return this.credentialService.getAwsSDK().adviserFundAdviseGet({
      'adviser': this.credentialService.$id,
      'fund': fund
    }, {}, {});
  }
```

here's the code I use to call the above SDK function and print it on console

```
this.http.getFundAdvisesList(fund.fundName)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response); // change in numbers seen in console
```

Here's few images which show the difference in data from network tab to browser console

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7HCwcSUzwkGWVRKbmo4cW9BSFk/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7HCwcSUzwkGRlhVNG1XMXJvQlU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The exact reason is not none but it was due to the code written after the console.log line.

and since java-script is asynchronous by default - the printed data was changed by the other part of the code. Mainly it was happening at the line wherever I was converting received array of data into a particular object (typescript model)